# using ie9 as an ie7

Tags: webbrowser-control

i am using ie9 but sometimes i have to use ie7 or ie8 and i don't want to uninstal it can i turn ie9 to ie7 if it is needed?

Answer (score 3):

I don't currently have IE9 so I can't verify, but I have installed it temporarily in the past and believe this functionality exists.

In, IE, press `F12` to bring up the Developer Tools.  Towards the right side of the toolbar in this popup window, there should be a "Browser Mode" or something, which you can change between different versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test web pages try IETester http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage you have from version 5 to 8 and if you want it for normal use try to install IE in seprate folders.